# traefik HTTP POST request net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, traefik-authentication, traefik-plugins

I am trying to install [This docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/openspeedtest/latest)

which runs on port 3000 for http and 3001 for https.

I need to run just HTTP version on a LocalNetwork.

I am getting network error in browser console when upload test is running.

[image]

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.8"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5001:8080"
     
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  openspeedtest:
    image: "openspeedtest/latest"
    container_name: "speedtest-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest.rule=Host(`unraid.vishnu.pro`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest.entrypoints=web"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why i need to add

`"traefik.http.middlewares.limit.buffering.maxRequestBodyBytes`

now it is working for me.

mytraefik yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.8.0
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
    ports:
      - 5000:80
      - 5001:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  openspeedtest:
    image: openspeedtest/latest
    container_name: speedtest-service
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest.rule=Host(`192.168.1.15`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.limit.buffering.maxRequestBodyBytes=10000000000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest.middlewares=limit"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest-https.rule=Host(`192.168.1.15`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest-https.entrypoints=websecure"
      # - "traefik.http.middlewares.limit.buffering.maxRequestBodyBytes=10000000000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest-https.middlewares=limit"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest-https.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.openspeedtest-https.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
```